# Ajax click for facebook app iframe on iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone, ajax, facebook, facebook-iframe

I'd like to fix this issue but I can't do it so far. My iPhone has to click twice to show the Ajax friends selector for facebook App. The first click shows only the background tint, and I have to click the tint to remove it, and the second click show the friends selector jquery.friend.selector-1.2.js. The Android phone seems to be working. It would be great if anyone knows how to fix this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function logResponse(response) {
    if (console && console.log) {
      console.log('The response was', response);
    }
  }
  var friends = [];
  $(function(){
   FB.init({
      appId      : '<?php echo AppInfo::appID(); ?>', // App ID
      channelUrl : 'https://<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; ?>/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true // parse XFBML
  });
  FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(200);
  FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);
  FB.Canvas.setSize({width: 810, height: 1000});

var i = 0;
    $(".selectFriend").click(function(e){

    var selector = $(this);


    // init new selector

    selector.fSelector({
     max: 5,
     closeOnSubmit : true ,
     onSubmit: function(response){
      if(response){
// to rest old selected
var friend = $('.selectedFriendNames').attr('id');
var friendname = $('.selectedFriendNames').val();
var match = jQuery.inArray(friend,friends);
if($('.selectedFlower') && match >= 0){
//commented out for testing
//reduce count
//i--;
/*friends.splice(match,1);
$('.selectFriend').show();
$('.selectedFlower').find('.selectedFriendClass').html('');
$('.selectedFlower').find('#flowerName').removeAttr( 'style' );
$('.selectedFlower').find('.description').removeAttr( 'style' );
$('.selectedFlower').find('.comment').html('');
$('.selectedFlower').removeClass("selectedFlower");
$('#selections').val('');
$('#image').val('');
$('#icon').val('');
$('#desc').val('');
$('#fdesc').val('');
*/
} 
  i++;       
      var selections = response.join(',');
             $.post('renderSelectedUsers.php',{selections: selections,id:i},function(resp) {
             selector.closest('li').find('.selectedFriendClass').html(resp);
       selector.closest('li').find('.description').css("position", "relative");
       selector.closest('li').find('#flowerName').css("position", "absolute");
       selector.closest('li').find('#flowerName').css("top", "10px");
       selector.closest('li').find('#flowerName').css("left", "40px");
             selector.closest('li').find('.comment').html("<textarea name ='comment" + i + "' id= 'comment' placeholder= 'message!'/>");
             $('#selectedFriendsHtml' + i).val(resp);
       $('#count').val(i);
       selector.closest('li').find('.username').html($('.selectedFriendNames').html());
       friends.push($('.selectedFriendNames').attr('id'));
       var desc       = selector.closest('li').find('p').first().text();
       var fdesc      = selector.closest('li').find('.forConfirm').html();
        selector.closest('li').addClass("selectedFlower");
        var image_to_post = "<?php echo AppInfo::getUrl(); ?>"+selector.closest('li').find('img').first().attr
        ("src");
          var image = "<?php echo AppInfo::getUrl(); ?>"+selector.closest('li').find('.icon img').attr
        ("src");
         var icon = "<?php echo AppInfo::getUrl(); ?>"+selector.closest('li').find('#flowerName').attr
        ("src");
        $('#selections' + i).val(selections);
        $('#image' + i).val(image);
        $('#icon' + i).val(icon);
        $('#desc' + i).val(desc);
        $('#fdesc' + i).val(fdesc);
        $('#imageToPost' + i).val(image_to_post);
      });
          selector.hide();
    }
   }
  });
  });
  });
  function submitForm(){
    if( $('#selections').val() !='' && $('#comment').val() !='' )

     $('#flowerForm').submit();
     else{
      alert("Select Friends");
     }
  }
</script>
```